# How to use .witx definitions for Go code generation to use with TinyGo WebAssembly targeting WASI?

Tags: go, webassembly, fastly, wasi, tinygo

Is it possible to use `.witx` definition files for Go code generation to use with TinyGo's WebAssembly WASI (WebAssembly System Interface) support?

Specifically, I want to create a Fastly Compute@Edge SDK for Go. These SDKs exist for JavaScript, AssemblyScript, Rust, Swift, and Zig, but not Go yet. This requires WebAssembly with WASI support which TinyGo has, but I haven't found any information on using WITX files yet.

[Fastly says the following](https://developer.fastly.com/learning/compute/custom/):

> To execute your Wasm applications on Compute@Edge (and the local testing server), you need to use our Compute@Edge hostcalls, which are defined at https://github.com/fastly/Viceroy/tree/main/lib/compute-at-edge-abi. These `.witx` files define the functionality of Compute@Edge. Use them with your chosen language's WASI tooling to generate stubs or interfaces for your custom SDK to implement.

The `.witx` files are here:

- [`compute-at-edge.witx`](https://github.com/fastly/Viceroy/blob/ccf38c194f07ebd4a63cae64510aab9211ee7a03/lib/compute-at-edge-abi/compute-at-edge.witx)
- [`typenames.witx`](https://github.com/fastly/Viceroy/blob/ccf38c194f07ebd4a63cae64510aab9211ee7a03/lib/compute-at-edge-abi/typenames.witx)

[Wasm by Example](https://wasmbyexample.dev/examples/wasi-hello-world/wasi-hello-world.go.en-us.html) indicates that TinyGo can be used to target WASM with WASI support:

> Let's compile our `main.go` into a Wasm module that targets WASI!
>
> This can be down with the `-wasm-abi=generic` and `-target=wasi` flags when you run the TinyGo compiler:
>
> `tinygo build -wasm-abi=generic -target=wasi -o main.wasm main.go`
>
> Which should output (`-o`) a `main.wasm` file that we can run in a WebAssembly runtime that supports WASI!

It seems that a Go code generator that reads `.wtix` files and generates Go code is needed. Does one exist?

If not, it seems like the three approaches would be:

1. Extend a common code generator with Go support, likely written in a different language. For example, [WITX-CodeGen](https://github.com/jedisct1/witx-codegen) exists without Go support yet and is written in Rust. This would be like using the Java-based [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) to create Go REST API server stubs using [OpenAPI Spec](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification).
2. Create a Go-based `.witx` code generator.
   This could be like the Go-based [OAPI CodeGen](https://github.com/deepmap/oapi-codegen) for OpenAPI Spec.
3. Create the Go definitions manually, which would likely be a pre-cursor for either of the code gen approaches.